# HIbernate Criteria with two tables and collection

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have two tables,

```
Table Customer
ID  |  CustomerNumber  |  Name  |  City  |  PhoneNumber

Table Accounts
ID  |  CustomerNumber  |  AccountNumber  |  Bank
```

The relationship between the two tables is CustomerNumber

My Customer mapping

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer ID;
    @Column(name = "CustomerNumber")
    private Integer customerNumber;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "City")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "PhoneNumber")
    private Integer phoneNumber;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customerNumber")
    private Collection<Account> accounts;
}
```

And the Account mapping

```
public class Account {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer ID;
    @JoinColumn(name = "CustomerNumber", referencedColumnName="CustomerNumber")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Customer customer;
    @Column(name = "AccountNumber")
    private Integer accountNumber;
    @Column(name = "Bank")
    private String bank;
}
```

Function i DAO

```
public SearchResult listByCriteria(Customer object, int maxResults, String sortProperty, boolean ascending) {
    SearcResult result = new SearchResult();
    int resultSize = 0;
    Criteria customerCriteria = ((Session)em.getDelegate()).createCriteria(Customer.class);
    if(maxResults > 0) {
        customerCriteria.setMaxResults(maxResults);
    }
    try {
        if(object != null) {
            customerCriteria = QueryHelper.getCustomerCriteria(object, customerCriteria, "");
            resultSize = QueryHelperUtil.countResults(customerCriteria);
            result.setSize(resultSize);
            customerCriteria.setFirstResult(index);
            QueryHelperUtil.sortResults(customerCriteria, sortProperty, ascending);
            result.setList(customerCriteria.list());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        error(ex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

QueryHelper.getCustomerCriteria

```
public static Criteria getCustomerCriteria(Customer object, Criteria criteria, String alias) {
    if (object != null) {
        if (object.getCustomerNumber() != null && object.getCustomerNumber() > 0) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(alias+"customerNumber", object.getCustomerID()));
        }
        if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(object.getName())) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like(alias+"name", QueryHelperUtil.createLikeStatement(object.getName())));
        }
        if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(object.getCity())) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like(alias+"city", QueryHelperUtil.createLikeStatement(object.getCity())));
        }
        if (object.getPhoneNumber())) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(alias+"phoneNumber", object.getPhoneNumber()));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to search for customers with bank accounts only. And I want to setup a criteria in Hibernate. But I just don't know how to do this?

When searching you could enter customerNumber, name of customer, phonenumber and/or city and select how many results you want to display.

First I thought I could write a named query, but then you have the search result number and the functionality of sorting the result on different columns.

I have search here and looked at the different similar questions but I just can't get it to work.
I tried to add a criteria for account in a function for listing customers by criteria but it just doesn't work and I don't know if it has something to do with the account being a collection?

Could anyone help me please?

### **Solution**

I added the following in my method listbycriteria

```
customerCritera.setFetchMode("accounts",FetchMode.JOIN);
Criteria accountCriteria = customerCriteria.createAlias("accounts","accounts");
```

Between **if(Object != null)** and **resultSize = QueryHelperUtil.countResults(customerCriteria);**

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, do you already have a DAO with query that doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I have a DAO class with a listByCriteria function that lists all customers by specific critera on customernumber, name, city and phonenumber. But I would like to add the criteria with accounts so that I only get customers _with_ a bank account. This is only for a specific view in the application.

Right now there is a function that list all customers and then there is a call to db to find the account for each customer.
But all customers doesn't have an account so right now there are a lot of unnecessary calls to db.

Comment: Could you add the specific fubction of the DAO class to your question?

Comment: You just have to do an inner join from Customer to Account, which will return only customers which have at least one account.

Comment: Added function to my question.

@Jakob But how do I do this? I suck at joins when it comes to criteria and hibernate :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not exactly know how you determinante what account is a bank account. 
However, you probably would like to have something like this:

```
   Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Customer.class,"cust");
   criteria.createAlias("cust.accounts","acc");
   criteria.list();
```

To check if the account has a bank number add:

```
.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("acc.bank"));
```

before the .list()